# Error while uploading to ESP8266 from Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I was trying to upload code to my esp8266 from the Arduino IDE and it gives me this error:

```
   esptool.py v2.8
    Serial port COM6
    Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\arcae_000\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
        esptool.main(cmdline)
      File "C:/Users/arcae_000/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
        esp.connect(args.before)
      File "C:/Users/arcae_000/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
        raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
    esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
    esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

I have the esp8266 board extension installed on the Arduino IDE and set to 'Generic ESP8266 Module'. I have tried changing the upload speed but it still fails. This is the code I used:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "SSID";//type your ssid
const char* password = "PASSWORD";//type your password

int ledPin = 2; // GPIO2 of ESP8266
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);


  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request

  int value = LOW;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    value = HIGH;
  } 
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    value = LOW;
  }

// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);


  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("On");  
  } else {
    client.print("Off");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=ON\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 ON<br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 OFF<br>");
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```

**(I have changed the SSID and Password values)**
I have searched every website I could find but I still couldn't fix it. The esp8266 is in flash mode. Also, I know that the esp8266 is not broken. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: is the esp8266 in flashing mode? (io 0 LOW at startup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your upload settings?

Things that might be wrong:

- You maybe have a NODEMCU module, try to switch to that board in upload settings.
- Did you confirm that a new COM-port shows up when you plugin your ESP?
- Do you have the correct COM-port selected?

These are my ESP8266 settings, 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrOMf.png)

In case you actually have a NODEMCU, if nothing is working from above, try updating the firmware using all these instructions : https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by updating the firmware

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same error, I found this solution and its work for me.
The most common reason for the board not being displayed on a port are a failing USB connection. The board needs to be connected to your computer with a data USB cable. Make sure the USB cable is not damaged. Test your cable with a different device or try using a different cable.